# How to fix "File was loaded in the wrong encoding: UTF-8" in PyCharm?

Tags: python, encoding, pycharm, pickle

I'm trying to save information in a file using pickle but when I open the file the information isn't stored in binary format and I get the message

> "File was loaded in the wrong encoding: UTF-8"

```py
import pickle

with open('text.pickle', 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump('some text', file)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open a pickle file, in Python you'll need to use `pickle.load()`

```py
infile = open('text.pickle', 'rb')
new_dict = pickle.load(infile)
infile.close()
```

Look at [this article](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/pickle-python-tutorial) on working with pickle